# Do doctors have the legal responsibility to inform the patient of services not covered by the insurance in the USA?

Tags: united-states, california, massachusetts, health-insurance

I wonder whether doctors have the legal responsibility to inform the patient of services not covered by the insurance in the USA.

https://craighospital.org/resources/you-and-your-doctor-rights-and-responsibilities states that:

> Your doctor has the responsibility [...] to inform you of services not covered by insurance.

However, it does not point to any law, so I don't know whether this is a legal requirement.

I am most interested in California and Massachusetts.